# Why does ggplotly lose my scale_size_continuous legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, ggplotly

I am developing a Shiny app to interactively display a bubbleplot using ggplot2, and I would like to add plotly functionality to it. The following creates data for a reproducible example:

```
# Load packages
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(tidyverse)

# create data
Name <- c(rep(c("Red Pine", "Sugar Maple"), each = 125))
mean.SDI <- c(rnorm(250, 150, 150)) 
mean.SDI <- mean.SDI + abs(min(mean.SDI))
DI <- c(rep(c(rep(c(1:5), 25)), 2))
PI <- c(rep(c(rep(c(1:5), each = 25)), 2))
GrowthRate <- c(rnorm(250, 2.5, 1))
GrowthRate[GrowthRate < 0] <- 0
n <- as.integer(runif(250, min = 1, max = 50))

trend_data <- tibble(Name, mean.SDI, DI, PI, GrowthRate, n)
```

The following script that DOES NOT use plotly produces the desired result:

```
# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("lumen"),
            titlePanel("Growth rates"),
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(

                selectInput(inputId = "Species", label = strong("Species"),
                            choices = unique(trend_data$Name)[order(unique(trend_data$Name))],
                            selected = "Red Pine"),
                sliderInput(inputId = "SDI", label = strong("Stand density index"),
                            min = 0, max = 1100, value = c(0, 800), dragRange = TRUE)
              ),

              mainPanel(
                fluidRow(column(6, plotOutput(outputId = "bubbleplot", height = "400px", width = "600px"))
              )
            )
        )
)


# Define server function

server <- function(input, output) {

 # Subset data
 DI_PI <- reactive({
trend_data %>%
  filter(
    Name == input$Species,
    mean.SDI >= input$SDI[1] & mean.SDI <= input$SDI[2]
  ) %>%
  group_by(DI, PI) %>%
  summarize(GrowthRate = mean(GrowthRate),
            n = as.numeric(sum(n))) %>%
  mutate(nAlpha = n > 50)

 })


 # Create scatterplot object the plotOutput function is expecting
 output$bubbleplot <- renderPlot({
p <- ggplot(DI_PI(), aes(x = DI, y = PI, size = GrowthRate, alpha = nAlpha)) +
  geom_point(col = '#236AB9') +
  xlab("DI Class") +
  ylab("PI Class") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 5), ylim = c(1,5)) +
  scale_size_continuous(name = "Subplot-level Growth Rate \n (ft2 per acre per year)",
                        range = c(0.1, 15)) +
  scale_alpha_discrete(labels = c("Less than 50 subplots", "At least 50 subplots"),
                       name = "")
print(p)

 })

 } 


# Create Shiny object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, when I add plotly to this (because I want the plots to be interactive), I lose the size legend:

```
  # Define UI
  ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("lumen"),
            titlePanel("Growth rates"),
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(

                selectInput(inputId = "Species", label = strong("Species"),
                            choices = unique(trend_data$Name)[order(unique(trend_data$Name))],
                            selected = "Red Pine"),
                sliderInput(inputId = "SDI", label = strong("Stand density index"),
                            min = 0, max = 1100, value = c(0, 800), dragRange = TRUE)
              ),

              mainPanel(
                fluidRow(column(6, plotlyOutput(outputId = "bubbleplot", height = "400px", width = "600px"))
              )
            )
        )
)


# Define server function

server <- function(input, output) {

# Subset data
DI_PI <- reactive({
trend_data %>%
  filter(
    Name == input$Species,
    mean.SDI >= input$SDI[1] & mean.SDI <= input$SDI[2]
  ) %>%
  group_by(DI, PI) %>%
  summarize(GrowthRate = mean(GrowthRate),
            n = as.numeric(sum(n))) %>%
  mutate(nAlpha = n > 50)

})

# Create scatterplot object the plotOutput function is expecting
output$bubbleplot <- renderPlotly({
p <- ggplot(DI_PI(), aes(x = DI, y = PI, size = GrowthRate, alpha = nAlpha)) +
  geom_point(col = '#236AB9') +
  xlab("DI Class") +
  ylab("PI Class") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 7), ylim = c(1,5)) +
  scale_size_continuous(name = "Subplot-level Growth Rate \n (ft2 per acre per year)",
                        range = c(0.1, 15)) +
  scale_alpha_discrete(labels = c("Less than 5 subplots", "At least 5 subplots"),
                       name = "")
ggplotly(p)

})

}

 # Create Shiny object
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It seems that ggplotly has had issues with displaying legends. Is anyone aware of a good solution to this for the "scale_size" type of legends?

Using RStudio version 1.1.453 and plotly v 4.8.0

R info:
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
system         x86_64, mingw32
status
major          3
minor          5.0
year           2018
month          04
day            23
svn rev        74626
language       R
version.string R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
nickname       Joy in Playing

********EDIT: tried removing "alpha" aesthetic to restrict to only one legend (for "size"), but now there is no legend plotted at all:

```
# EDIT server function

server <- function(input, output) {

# Subset data
DI_PI <- reactive({
trend_data %>%
  filter(
    Name == input$Species,
    mean.SDI >= input$SDI[1] & mean.SDI <= input$SDI[2]
  ) %>%
  group_by(DI, PI) %>%
  summarize(GrowthRate = mean(GrowthRate),
            n = as.numeric(sum(n))) %>%
  mutate(nAlpha = n > 50)

})


# Create scatterplot object the plotOutput function is expecting
output$bubbleplot <- renderPlotly({
p <- ggplot(DI_PI(), aes(x = DI, y = PI, 
                         #alpha = nAlpha, 
                         size = GrowthRate)) +
  geom_point(col = '#236AB9') +
  xlab("DI Class") +
  ylab("PI Class") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 7), ylim = c(1,5)) +
  scale_size_continuous(name = "Subplot-level Growth Rate \n (ft2 per acre per year)",
                        range = c(0.1, 15)) #+
  #scale_alpha_discrete(labels = c("Less than 5 subplots", "At least 5 subplots"),
                       #name = "")
ggplotly(p)

})

}

# Create Shiny object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `plotly` does not usually like two legends. You will find similar questions on SO.

Comment: Thank you for this info; I edited my script to remove the "alpha" but do not quite understand why no legend is plotted even though there should only be one legend to plot.

Comment: looks like it might be a bug. It would not be the first time (https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/300).